# Download 1000s of images using api

Tags: php, cron, fork

I have to download 1000s of images using api in cron job. Code is working fine but I want to optimize it. I want like,if I have to download 1000 images. Master file will divide job into 10 parts (100 images download each) and allocate job to 10 files(may be 10 instance of same file) 10*100 = 1000 images (like multi-threading). I can do with curl But it's on same server, so is there should be faster way to run files?I want to make like multi-threading. Master file will be called by cron job, rest work should be like multi-threading. Is $pid = pcntl_fork(); is good and safe way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a high performance HTTP crawler / downloader is no easy task. I'll describe, how I'd do it. Keep in mind, there are a lot of solutions, so if you want to dive deeper into this topic, you may want to read [Modern Operating Systems by Andrew S. Tanenbaum](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136006639).

1. Put all URL's that need to be downloaded into a database.
2. The master process connects the database and determines how many downloads there are and uses this parameter to set the download amount for the workers. **It then closes the database connection.**
3. The master process uses [`pcntl_fork()`](http://php.net/pcntl_fork) to start the amount of workers you wish to run. (Yes, it's safe, but it's not easy to use.)
4. Each worker should connect to the database **separately** and establish a read-write lock on the URL's it wishes to process. In case of MySQL, you'd use [`SELECT... FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).
5. The worker should **mark the records it processes** with it's PID as in progress within the database, then release the database lock.
6. The worker processes the download, then updates the database that it's finished.
7. Once all workers have finished with their share and exited (see [`pcntl_wait()`](http://php.net/pcntl_wait)), the master process opens a database connection and clears all in-progress flag that any crashed workers may have left. It then closes the database connection.
8. The process is repeated until all downloads are complete.

This is a *relatively* safe path to travel. However, keep in mind that you are playing with something way beyond the knowledge level of an average (or even experienced) PHP coder. You **must** read up on how the Linux (or Windows) process model works, otherwise you will have an incredibly broken application at your hands.